# Make NPM package dynamically install its own dependencies

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm

I'm writing an NPM package that's going to support several databases. I'm working on a CLI at the moment that, passed a connection URI string, it will install the appropriate dialect for that database. e.g. if passed a URI that contains `postgresql://...` it will install the `pg` and `pg-hstore` packages with a command like `npm install pg pg-hstore` (or yarn depending on lock file).

I'm running into the issue where this will then install the package in the root projects `package.json` so now my package does not have access to the `pg` package.

How do I either:
A) get access to top-level packages that are NOT in my packages `package.json`

B) Have my package install the correct package for its own `package.json`